# how background music pause and play when my app video is play in swift 3

Tags: swift3, avplayer, avaudiosession

I have created a small video application but when i play video the background music pause. but i want to play music again when video pause and when i play video again than music player will resume.

i tiered most of links but did't get result

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [.duckOthers])
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

when i use this than both are playing but i want to pause music when video play and if video pause than background music play.same like Whatsapp

Any ideas or feedback on possible ways is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [.duckOthers])
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

looks like you have created instance every time, 
dose it initialize every time, if so then it will start music from first every time.

so try to make it global.

Comment: thanks for answer but this is not solution because i trigger this instance on viewDidAppear().

Comment: and this code is working but play background audio and video parallel.

Answer (score 0):

**This Latest swift3 Code**

You can use avPlayerViewController  it can be default pause and play all setting can be available.So you can just add two frame works to the projects.Those frameworks are

1)AV Kit Framework
               2)AV Foundation FrameWork
Import those frameworks into your class and create objects to players and you add mp3 file or mp4 file to your projects navigation or otherwise from url also used

```
      import UIKit
      import AVFoundation
      import AVKit



class ViewController: UIViewController {
var player = AVAudioPlayer()
let avPlayer = AVPlayer()

var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

@IBOutlet var vedioPlayer: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




        }
```

Play song  use this code

```
         func playButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "01 O Rangula Chilaka", withExtension: "mp3")!
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {




        playerViewController.player!.play()

    }


}
```

Play video use this code its for mp4 file added to your project or url also use to play the video

```
    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = vedioPlayer.bounds
    vedioPlayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
```

This code used for mp4 file in your projects

```
      let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Shakthi - Premadesam Yuvarani", withExtension: "mp4")!
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    videoPlayer.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)//videoPlayer is the uiview  the vide0plays only that view.
   let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {




        playerViewController.player!.play()

    }
```

Comment: i try this code but not work at all... when i play mp3 from mp3 from saavan after i start video from my application background music pause but when i pause video from my app music not started...so your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 in AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
        // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**finally get solution but its working only default system music player only**

[reference link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller)

**First give permission to music player...**

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

**you can pause or play default music player here is the code**

```
import MediaPlayer

var defaultPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
defaultPlayer.play() 
//you can also pause defaultPlayer.pause()
//get current title defaultPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.title
//get current playbacktime defaultPlayer.player.currentPlaybackTime
```